# In python, add two lists in this way: ['a','b']+['c']= [['a','b'],['c']. How do i do this?

Tags: python, list, addition

How do I add two lists, such that the resulting list keeps the other lists intact:

```
['5','6','7'] + ['1'] + ['9','7'] = [['5','6','7'], ['1'], ['9','7']]
```

Is it possible to do this in python?

Current code:

```
def appendy(list_o_list): 
    temp_l = [] 
    for l in list_o_list: 
        temp_l.append(list(l)) 
        new_list=[] 
        new_list = [a + b for a, b in itertools.combinations(temp_l, 2)]                    
        print("app",new_list) 
return (new_list) 

appendy([('g3', 'g1'), ('g3', 'g2')])
```

Comment: That's not adding lists, that's putting those lists into an additional list.

Comment: did you mean appending list?

Comment: you are right jon. I do want to put two lists in an additional list

Answer (score 1):

Its not adding lists, it is appending lists. Its quite easy to just do with .append()

Just do:

```
resulting_list = []
resulting_list.append(lista)
resulting_list.append(listb)
resulting_list.append(listc)
```

All the original lists will remain the same and `resulting_list` will contain the joined lists. What you are trying to do is not completely clear.

Comment: def appendy(list_o_list):
        temp_l=[]
        for l in list_o_list:
                temp_l.append(list(l))
        new_list=[]
        new_list = [a + b for a, b in itertools.combinations(temp_l, 2)]
        print("app",new_list)
        return (new_list)
appendy([('g3', 'g1'), ('g3', 'g2')])

Comment: @SatyamRaha why would you think posting your code in a comment is any-way reasonable?

Comment: its kinda messy...may be u can get some idea about what i am trying to do. appendy finds all possible permutations from a list "list_o_list"

Comment: i did post my code to just let you know that your solution doesn't really solve my problem

Comment: @SatyamRaha, post your code as an edit to your question. The comments is not the right place for that. I added it this time.

Answer (score 0):

`+` implies concatenation of objects, so intuitively:

```
[5, 6, 7] + [8, 9]
= [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As mentioned by Darkchili Slayer, you embed lists in another list by appending. In fact, a rather simple solution is to just do:

```
Python 3.4.2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [5, 6, 7]
>>> b = [8, 9]
>>> c = []
>>> c.append(a)
>>> c.append(b)
>>> c
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

If you want to get fancy, you can do something like this using the special [variable argument operator, *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs#3394898):

```
>>> def join_l(*lists):
...     temp = []
...     for l in lists:
...         temp.append(l)
...     return temp
...
>>> join_l([5, 6, 7], [8, 9])
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

You can even do it this way too, and make it a bit easier to read:

```
def join_l(*lists):
...     return list(lists)
...
>>> join_l([5, 6, 7], [8, 9])
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Finally, it's worth noting that there is an `extend` function for lists, which appends each item in another list. You can use this to simplify the first example:

```
>>> a = [5, 6, 7]
>>> b = [8, 9]
>>> c = []
>>> c.extend([a, b])
>>> c
[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

In this case, the `extend` function isn't very useful because the input is exactly the same as its output.